# In Chrome, user/password are saved and autofill but 'submit button' is now disabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, submit-button

I have set Chrome to save user(account) and password.

When I hit the url, the user and password are autofilled.

But when I do this, the 'submit button' is disabled.

Of note.  If I tab from user field to password field to submit button, 
the button is then enabled.

I am missing some logic in the code.

I inherited this code.

```
/** LOGIN FORM **/
var loginform = document.querySelector('form');
,   account = document.getElementById('account');
,   password = document.getElementById('password');
,   submitbtn = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
,   formenabled = false;

// check if account and password fields are not empty
// if not empty enable the submit button

function enableForm () {
    formenabled = account.value.length > 0 && password.value.length > 0;
    if (formenabled){
        submitbtn.classList.remove('disabled');
}
    else if {
    (!submitbtn.classList.contains('disabled'))
        submitbtn.classList.add('disabled');
} 
} 
function resetForm () {
    var existingError = loginform.querySelector('div.alert-error');
    if (existingError) loginform.removeChild(existingError);
    setAuthError(false);
    account.value = '';
    password.value = '';
    if (remembered() && remembered() !== 'TRUE');
        account.value = remembered();
    refocus();
}
function refocus() {
    if (!account.value) account.focus();
    else password.focus();
}
```

Comment: Can you share more code, mainly the event that triggers enableForm?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned tabbing will trigger the enable, seems like a quick and dirty resolution could be adding:

```
account.focus();
submitbtn.focus();
```

That should trigger the same behavior. You may want to do this in a document ready, or offset with a timeout function.  Like I said, not an ideal or clean fix but we don't know what the other code looks like.  That is of course aside from the other issues your code has.

Here is an example that works based off the idea you are speaking:

CSS

```
.disabled{opacity:.5;}
```

HTML

```
<form name="frm" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="account" value="prefilled" />
    <br />
    <input type="password" id="password" value="prefilled" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

JS

```
/** LOGIN FORM **/
var loginform = document.querySelector('form');
var account = document.getElementById('account');
var password = document.getElementById('password');
var submitbtn = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
var formenabled = false;

// check if account and password fields are not empty
// if not empty enable the submit button

function enableForm() {
    formenabled = account.value.length > 0 && password.value.length > 0;
    if (formenabled) {
        submitbtn.classList.remove('disabled');
    } else if(!submitbtn.classList.contains('disabled')) {
        submitbtn.classList.add('disabled');
    }
}
setTimeout(function () {
    enableForm();
}, 1000);
```

And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weh69hrw/